# Angular 7 used in .net MVC view, how to support watch real time changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, watch

I am working to refactor a legacy MVC5 application and in oder to include the output of the Angular build process into views, I decided to use the Bundling functionality offered by Asp.net framework, it all works, in dev and production mode (so I correctly handle cache busting).
The missing problem I am trying to solve, is to support dynamic updates triggered by the watch build option (live reload in the serve command), so below some snippet of codes to show what I did so far.

**Bundle configuration**

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // Bundle QSB scripts and styles
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/js/QSB")
            .Include(
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/runtime.*",
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/es2015-polyfills.*",
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/polyfills.*",
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/styles.js",
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/vendor.*",
                "~/Content/ng/QSB/main.*"));

       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/QSB")
            .Include("~/Content/ng/QSB/*.css"));
    }
```

**Angular configuration**

```
    [...]
    "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../BackendProjectFolder/Content/ng/QSB",
        "index": "projects/qsb/src/index.html",
        "main": "projects/qsb/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "projects/qsb/src/polyfills.ts",
    [...]
```

When developing I first execute the command *ng b --watch*, once ready I start debugging the application, in order to see the changes I need to hit F5 refreshing the browser page.

In the development machine the mvc application is hosted in IIS and always available.

Is there a way to simulate the live reload available with the serve command?
Any suggestion?